# jquery only toggling when clicking on li and not on nested li

Tags: jquery, nested, toggle

I got the following situation:

http://jsfiddle.net/7XrUM/

with this js for the toggling:

```
$("ul > li.closed").click(function() {
    var li = $(this).closest('li');
    li.find(' > ul').slideToggle('fast');
    $(this).toggleClass("closed open");
});
```

When clicking on "Headline", the ul is shown. But when I then click on an image or between them, they toggle back and are being hidden again. So I just want to toggle when clicking on "Headline" and not when clicking on some of the nested elements, but I can't get this one to work.

Answer (score 3):

Just check if it actually was the `LI` that was clicked, and not an event that just bubbled:

```
$("ul > li.closed").click(function(e) {
    if (e.target === this) {
        var li = $(this).closest('li');
        li.find(' > ul').slideToggle('fast');
        $(this).toggleClass("closed open");
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7XrUM/2/)

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. Always nice to learn new things :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function () {
    $("li.closed > ul").hide();

    $("ul > li.closed").click(function () {
        var li = $(this).closest('li');
        li.find(' > ul').slideToggle('fast');
        $(this).toggleClass("closed open");
    });

    $("li.fl, li.fl > a").click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7XrUM/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Best thing for you to do would be to wrap the action element in a HTML tag to have more control:

```
<ul>
    <li class="closed"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Headline 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="fl"><a href="#"><img src="#"></a></li>
            <li class="fl"><a href="#"><img src="#"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    ...       
</ul>
```

This way you will not need to worry if you click anything inside the UL that would close the shown area.

```
$("ul > li.closed a").click(function() {
    var li = $(this).closest('li');
    li.find(' > ul').slideToggle('fast');
    $(this).toggleClass("closed open");
});
```